# SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10511: Signature validation failed

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey, KeyId: 'Development', InternalId: 'RoGk-RvQuBI4Mn1J8hdUpzlEH9v_caW7aALLjFqAoac'. I use .Net Core 5 and JwtBearer package latest version.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                var authenticationSettings = configuration
                    .GetSection(AuthenticationSettings.SectionName)
                    .Get<AuthenticationSettings>();

                options.Authority = authenticationSettings.Authority;
                options.Audience = authenticationSettings.Audience;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };

                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        Log.Warning(context.Exception, "OnAuthenticationFailed");

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnForbidden = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Result.Failure is not null)
                            Log.Warning(context.Result.Failure, "OnForbidden");

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

Sometimes some of my services starting to throw this exception, but other continue to work correctly. All have the same configuration(code above). What is wrong?

Comment: `Sometimes some of my services starting to throw this exception, but other continue to work correctly` If you can share a minimal, reproducible sample, we can easily reproduce and troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: It happens occasionally, so I can’t give you sample. It can work a few days and then some services fail, but other still working, maybe there is a bug in JwtBearer package

Comment: And by the way, introspection endpoint validates token successfully all the time. I have my own Identity Server 4